# Source for Squirrels Dislodging Nuts to Drive-Off Predators

Tags: zoology, behaviour

I was reading a recent article by the [Boston Globe](https://www.bostonglobe.com/2022/09/15/lifestyle/after-150-years-arnold-arboretum-has-foliage-down-pat/) on Harvard's Arnold Arboretum and it off-handily mentioned something very interesting:

> ‶I love the hickory collection,″ [Michael] Dosmann admits. ‶You have these tall trees that reach up to the heavens. You’re walking under a tall canopy of almost pure golden yellow.″ But be careful, Dosmann jokes. ‶**Sometimes the squirrels intentionally try to dislodge the hickory nuts while you are directly underneath, just to frighten you out of their territory.** You might get knocked in the head by a hickory nut, but it’s worth that gamble to experience the hickory collection in autumn.″

The idea of squirrels being able to drive away a predator like this is really amazing, but I am doubting if it is true. On one hand, [Dr. Dosmann](https://arboretum.harvard.edu/people/michael-s-dosmann/) has a PhD in Ecology from Cornell University and is the the head curator for the arboretum, so I don't think he is exaggerating to impress a reporter. On the other hand, this behavior would require a lot of intelligence and I question how effective it would be on any human-sized predator.

I could not find any other sources that mentioned this behavior, but that could just be because I am not sure what key words I should be searching for. Searching 'squirrel antipredator behavior' on Google Scholar mostly returns articles about when squirrels flee from a predator, but I can't think of another phrase that would describe this behavior.

Has anyone heard of squirrels driving possible predators off by dislodging nuts at them? If not, are there any similar behaviors in other organisms?

Comment: I've both heard of the hypothesis and experienced it (although their aim isn't that good). They don't do it every time you walk under a nut-bearing tree with a squirrel in it, though. It may depend on how habituated they are to humans in their territory. I am also struggling to find references.

Comment: One of the reasons I want a formal source is it is easy to see how this belief could come about through a bias in data collection. If squirrels drop nuts by accident at a constant rate, completely independent of humans' presence, then squirrels will only be observed to drop nuts when humans are nearby (since when there are no humans nearby, no one will observe the drops). Without video cameras or other equipment to measure how often nuts are dropped when humans are not nearby, I do not see how you could rule out this possibility.

Comment: Your thinking is correct, and I'm pretty sure the same point has occurred to Dr. Dossman. Maybe he can provide you with a source? I'm serious here; it's not that hard to reach scientists these days. Or you just may be correct.